# How to set listcontrol item to be highlighted?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I want to highlight listview item by default.I mean the by default first item should be highlighted .

Actually I did a sample but it is not working :(
Here is the code snippet I am using for Inserting Items to the list and setting the first row to get highlighted.

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    LVCOLUMN pColumn;
    pColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    pColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    pColumn.pszText = L"Product Name";
    pColumn.cx = 150;
    pColumn.iSubItem = 1;

    m_ListCtrl.InsertColumn(2, &pColumn);


    ::ZeroMemory(&pColumn, sizeof(LVCOLUMN));
    pColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    pColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    pColumn.pszText = L"Country";
    pColumn.cx = 150;
    pColumn.iSubItem = 2;

    m_ListCtrl.InsertColumn(3, &pColumn);

    LVITEM lvItem;

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 0;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = L"Himami";
    m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(&lvItem);

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = 1;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = L"Shampoo";
    m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(&lvItem);

    //Trying highlight first item in the list.
    m_ListCtrl.SetItemState(0, LVIS_SELECTED ,LVIS_SELECTED);

    m_ListCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

    return TRUE;
}

void CListControlFocusDlg::OnListViewItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT      *pResult)
{
     NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;

    if ((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED))
    {
        m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(m_ListCtrl.GetSelectionMark(), TRUE);
        m_ListCtrl.SetSelectionMark(0);
    }
}
```

After using SetItemState the list control is as follows:
List item is not highlighted.

[image]

But I want the item to be highlighted as in the below image.

[image]

After Implementing tab-order I am able to get the first item in the list highlighted.
[image]

But I am not able to uncheck the first item until unless I press down  arrow.when I press down arrow a rectangular selection is coming on to the first item of the list and now I am able to check or uncheck the highlighted item by pressing space bar.This is how the list looks like after I pressed down arrow.

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how can I check or uncheck the first item by pressing space bar without pressing down arrow for the rectangular selection.

Comment: Besides `LVIS_SELECTED` you also have to set the `LVIS_FOCUSED` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The cancel button looks like it has the focus.  The default behavior of Windows is to set the focus to the first item in the tab order.  I would suggest you use the resource editor to set the tab order.  The easiest way is to set the tab stop order of the items in the dialog and make the list control the first item.  The standard keystroke to edit the tab order is to hit Ctrl+D.

Comment: As you suggested I implemented the tab order and now it is working good I mean that the item is highlighted but I am not able to set check for the item through space bar,when press down arrow a rectangular selection is on the first item and then I am able to select the item through space bar.Can please let me know how can I set that rectangular selection to the first item by default along with highlighting the item and should be able to set check through space bar without pressing down arrow.

Comment: use SetCheck() function... It is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw67zt9d.aspx

Comment: @WinAppy, SetCheck() didn't made any change.As I told before when  I press down arrow , that rectangular selection is coming on to the first item and now I am able to check or un-check through space bar.And this behaviour I am expecting default .Can you please suggest me a way.And please refer my original post which is modified.

Comment: @Siva are you handling WM_KEYDOWM/WM_KEYUP?

Comment: @WinAppy no I am not handling.If I should use them what should I handle in that event and how ?

Comment: This may help you... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [LVN_ITEMCHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774845(v=vs.85).aspx) notification

```
void OnItemchangedList2(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;

    if ((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED))
    {
        m_ListCtrl.SetCheck(m_ListCtrl.GetSelectionMark(), TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Siva Can you update your code, so that we can have a look into that to find the solution. Because this has to work.

Comment: @Siva I couldn't see any functions other than OnInitDialog() on your original post(i mean your question).

Comment: Did you added notification to message maps. If yes, are you sure that the function is getting invoked on item selection change?

Comment: Yes it is being invoked .